# Inductively Coupled Plasma and Mass Spectrometry

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I was doing some homework and I was reading about how ICP is suitable for mass spectrometry and it said how its high temperature favours ionization which is good in MS. But also, because the temperature is so high in a plasma, wouldn't there be a very high collisional frequency which could cause side reactions/disruption of the signals, etc?